# PostgreSQL - Query tables' columns' size

Tags: postgresql

I want to know tables' columns' sizes, to limit inputs' length in the form (I'm also checking it in the backend).

How can I know this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12395731/3961156

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query, it returns all the column name, data type, maximum lengths for a given table 'table_name'.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name = 'table_name';
```

You could modify it to return one column replacing 'column_name' with yours like so:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name = 'table_name'
AND column_name = 'column_name';
```