# How to get size of PostgreSQL jsonb field?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with jsonb field in table.

```
CREATE TABLE data.items
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  datab jsonb
)
```

How to get size of this field in a query like this:

```
select id, size(datab) from data.items
```

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394538/calculating-the-size-of-a-column-type-in-postgresql

Comment: `pg_column_size()` or `pg_size_bytes()`  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For the number of bytes used to store:

```sql
select id, pg_column_size(datab) from data.items;
```

For the number of elements on the jsonb object:

```sql
select id, jsonb_array_length(datab) from data.items;
```

Comment: `pg_column_size` returns "Number of bytes used to store a particular value (possibly compressed)" for the curious https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-admin.html

Comment: is there a similar function that will return the number of elements in a jsonb[] object?

Comment: the second one only works for json arrays, not objects

Answer (score 11):

If the column uses EXTENDED storage (TOAST compression), you should use `octet_length(datab::text)` instead of `pg_column_size`

Comment: OP didn’t indicate whether the desired result is (compressed) size on disk or (uncompressed) size of the object.  `octet_length` is uncompressed size, which seems more useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

To count the json string size:

```
select length(jsonb_field::text) from test;
```