# pg_sizeof function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I love the `pg_typeof` function to get a type of a value, such as:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(1), pg_typeof(1.4);
integer  numeric
```

Is there a way to get the byte size of a value as well, doing something like:

```
SELECT pg_sizeof(1.4);
```

I know that for each data type I can go back to the documentation page and try and figure out what is what, but is there a way to do that interactively with a query?

Comment: `pg_column_size()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name amazing, thank you. Out of curiosity, why is numeric at 10 bytes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394538/calculating-the-size-of-a-column-type-in-postgresql

Comment: @David542 you can use NUMERIC(precision, scale)
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: @zac how do you calculate the size though of a decimal/numeric?

Comment: @David542 they say in the documentation it is variable

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) `numeric` is a variable length data type: https://dbfiddle.uk/Zn87j4O3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name is there a way to estimate the size before entering it in?

Comment: You mean a function that returns the size of a value without passing a value? how should that work?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no I mean just how to estimate size without calling a function, for example, the smallest number has 8 bytes, up until precision of 10 digits which has 10 bytes, up to... etc.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess it would be: `The actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead.`, but curious about the "three to eight" item.

Comment: @David542 I highly recommend this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966524/calculating-and-saving-space-in-postgresql/7431468#7431468

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pg_column_size`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-admin.html#:%7E:text=Description-,pg_column_size(any),-int) you can do something like:

```
select v, pg_typeof(v), pg_column_size(v) from (values (1)) _ (v) union ALL
select v, pg_typeof(v), pg_column_size(v) from (values (1.2)) _ (v) union ALL
select v, pg_typeof(v), pg_column_size(v) from (values (1e2)) _ (v)
```

[image]